# single dimension to multi dimension array in php

Tags: php

$results contains 3 single dimentional array

```
Array ( [0] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg) 
Array ( [0] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg) 
Array ( [0] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg)
```

i want a result:

```
Array ( [0] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg) 
Array ( [1] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg) 
Array ( [2] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg)
```

Comment: You probably want `Array ( [0] => '...', [1] => '...', [2] => '...' )` am I right ?

Comment: `$new_array[0] = $first_array[0];$new_array[1] = $second_array[0];$new_array[2] = $third_array[0];`

Comment: Use my code that i write in comment

Comment: i want that in single variable not in multiple variable

Comment: `$new_array` is single variable. The rest three are you first three single dimensional array variable. I just gave name

Answer (score 1):

solution 1:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($results as $key => $value){
 $new_array[] = $value[0];
}
```

or:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($results as $key => $value){
 $new_array[] = $value;
}
```

But the first solution is better because your array contains single value for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge

```
$arr1=array("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg"); 
$arr2=array("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg"); 
$arr3=array("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51z0h9unmsL._SL160_.jpg"); 
$arr=array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
```